# Presto - Failing to query Mongo Collection records

Tags: mongodb, presto, trino

I have Presto set-up done locally with mongodb connector and below is the catalog mongodb properties:

```
connector.name=mongodb
mongodb.seeds=my-mongodb:27017
mongodb.credentials=admin:password@mydb
mongodb.ssl.enabled=false
mongodb.case-insensitive-name-matching=true
```

One of the Collections is `local_geodata` and it has few columns and has around 5 records in it. However, when tried to query through Presto cli, it was throwing me an error as below:

```
presto> use mongodb.mydb;
USE
presto:mydb> show tables;
                                       Table                                       
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 local_geodata                                                                          
 presto_schema                                                                     
(2 rows)

presto:mydb> select * from local_geodata;
Query 20220213_152931_00039_3h2ec failed: Table has no columns: TableHandle {connectorId='mongodb', connectorHandle='mydb.local_geodata', layout='Optional.empty'}
```

Based on the documentation, to let Presto understand the schema to my collection, I went ahead and created a new collection `presto_schema` and added a new entry into this collection with the `local_geodata` collection schema and updated the catalog mongodb.properties with new entry `mongodb.schema-collection=presto_schema`, however, this time it identifies the Collection, but returns `0` records (The collection got 5 records in it).

Any inputs here please?

`Presto Version: 0.269`
`MongoDB Version: 4.4`

Data inside `presto_schema`

```
presto> select * from mongodb.geosnipe.presto_schema;
         table          |                                                                                       fields                                                                                        
------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 local_geodata | [{name=_id, type=ObjectId, hidden=true}, {name=city, type=varchar, hidden=false}, {name=country, type=varchar, hidden=false}, {name=ip, type=varchar, hidden=false}] 
 presto_schema          | [{name=_id, type=ObjectId, hidden=true}, {name=table, type=varchar, hidden=false}, {name=fields, type=array(row(name varchar,type varchar,hidden boolean)), hidden=false}]          
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Please share the data of `presto_schema`.

Comment: Updated the original question with `presto_schema` data.

Comment: Thanks and the schema collection seems valid. If you join Trino (formerly PrestoSQL) community Slack https://trino.io/slack.html, I can help you debug interactively.

Comment: @ebyhr - Did a close look at all my set-up and it seems I found the culprit and it is the collection name, which I named it as local_geoData and changing it to local_geodata (all small letters) started working fine. I was in an impression that `mongodb.case-insensitive-name-matching=true` property would handle it irrespective of its case sensitivity. Is there any additional configuration I need to add in order to make case insensitive to work properly? BTW, big thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a close look at all my set-up and it seems I found the culprit and it is the collection name, which I named it as `local_geoData` and changing it to `local_geodata` (all small letters), it started returning the data.